# JS - how to importe correctly image from public folder

Tags: javascript

I have an image in the public folder called logo.png

when I try to import it in my index.js file (src/view/index.js) :

```
import logo from "public/logo.png";
```

I always get this error :

```
Module not found: You attempted to import /public/logo.png which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.
```

Comment: Did you mean `"public/logo.png"`?

Comment: @SebastianSimon yes just edited thanks

Comment: Well, does it work?

Comment: @SebastianSimon ne it doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using an `<img>` element to display the image, it will have a `src` attribute. In that case, you can use the image url for the soruce. It looks like this:

```js
const logo = `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/logo.png`;
```

Then to render it, you would have something like this:

```
<img
    alt='my-logo'
    src={logo}
/>
```